# Making dynamically added component draggable

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm dynamically creating Angular component on click event using passed placeholder `ViewContainerRef` reference
(method `createComponent`). Then in the same method I'm using `modal.open` to open a new `NgbModal` dialog. Everything works smoothly, except dragging. With such approach unlike to my static markup dialogs, I cannot provide its draggable feature, because directive (`cdkDragDrop`) doesn't work for dynamically created content as far as I understand. So how to resolve this issue? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it in a bit hacky way:

```
  this.notificationModalRef = this.modalService.open(notificationComponentRef.instance.notificationContent, { centered: true, size: 'xl', scrollable: true });
  this.dragDrop.createDrag((this.notificationModalRef as any)._windowCmptRef.instance._dialogEl);
```